# Set Value as Required based on LOV choice

Tags: oracle-apex, oracle-apex-5

I want several fields to have "Required" parameter and template set to "Required - Above" if LOV value is set to "**Final**".

Otherwise (LOV set to "**Open**"), these fields should remain "Not Required" with template "Optional - Above".

[Report creation - if Decision Status is "Final", then Decision Category should be Required](https://i.stack.imgur.com/i288u.png)

Could you please help? For now I think Dynamic JavaScript Expression would do best.

Answer (score 0):

One option is to create dynamic action when LOV changed, execute JavaScript and use something like:

```
if ($('#P999_SELECT :selected').text() == "Final")
$(".t-Form-required").css({"display":"inline"});
else
$(".t-Form-required").css({"display":"none"});
```

Where my Select List is: P999_SELECT. You can make more conditions if you want. If you need to change required ot text field, make custom validation with condition Select List equal to Final or Open.I hope this can help you.